# Getting Master Current Binlog and Binlog Position in Replication Backup

Tags: mysql, backup, mysql-5.6, mysqldump

I want to take the current binlog file and binlog position of the master server in a `mysqldump` on the slave server. I cannot use `master-data=2` on slave - how can I do this nevertheless?

Comment: Welcome on the DBA SE! Pro tip: if you have a problem, don't forget any of this 3 key components: 1) what you want 2) what you tried 3) why it doesn't work. Good luck on the site!

Answer (score 2):

**Surprise, you can get the Master's binlog file/position from the dump !!! Use [*--dump-slave*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_dump-slave).**

MySQL 5.6 Documentation says :

> This option is similar to [--master-data](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_master-data) except that it is used to dump a replication slave server to produce a dump file that can be used to set up another server as a slave that has the same master as the dumped server. ***It causes the dump output to include a CHANGE MASTER TO statement that indicates the binary log coordinates (file name and position) of the dumped slave's master. These are the master server coordinates from which the slave should start replicating.***

Just get the `CHANGE MASTER TO` command from Lines 23-25 of the dump as always.

Comment: Hi Rolando , when i am using --dump-slave in my backup command ,i am getting these messages in my error log  ,1.  [Note] Slave I/O thread killed while reading event , 2.  [Note] Slave I/O thread exiting, read up to log 'myserv12.000822', position 9500xxxx , do i have to worry about this , and again it is getting reconnected to master

Comment: @JABIRBAIG `--dump-slave` is supposed to stop the SQL thread not the I/O Thread. The Documentation says : `This option causes mysqldump to stop the slave SQL thread before the dump and restart it again after.`. You should run `START SLAVE IO_THREAD;`. Watch the `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` to make sure the mysqldump turns the SQL thread back on. Do not run `START SLAVE` unless the mysqldump is done and replication is still disabled. Make sure you see `Slave_IO_Running : Yes` and `Slave_SQL_Running : Yes` when you run `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` after mysqldump is done.